# Prevent Android app to open default React Activity when the app is launched from Firebas Dynamic Link

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I developed a React Native app that has multiple Android Activities and one MainActivity.java that extends ReactActivity.

One of the Android Activity is a WebView that we launched from ReactActivity. This WebView will open a vendor url that triggers an OTP to sms or email. When user confirm the email or phone number through OTP, they will be redirected back to the app using Firebase dynamic link.

But instead of launching the current Android WebView activity the app is relaunching MainActivity (React Activity) by default.

How can I resume the current Activity instead of reopening React Activity?

I tried to move the intent filter for dynamic link to WebViewActivity in Android Manifest but still does not work.

```
<activity android:name=".WebViewActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<data android:host="appnamestage.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
<data android:host="appname.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to receive the intent in an existing instance of your Activity, you may set the `launchMode` of your Activity to **singleTask** in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<activity
  android:name=".YourActivity"
  android:launchMode="singleTask">
```